# SerialPort.IsOpen returns already opened in if condition

Tags: c#, .net-core, serial-port

I want to check if my serialport is already open before send data on it.

```
public static bool Send(SerialPortStream portStream, data)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!portStream.IsOpen)
            {
                portStream.Open();
            }
            

            if (portStream.IsOpen) // line 1973 returned error already 
                                   //opened
            {
                //build message and write on portstream
                try
                {
                    portStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            

        }
        return false;
    }
```

But the problem is that attribute class "IsOpen" catch error "serial port is already open" and the data is not sent. I don't understand why get attribute can't return me false value.

EDIT :
I use RJCP.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream class for my serialport.
Before the code above, i get the instance of the port from only one thread like this

```
public static bool Read(string port, ..data)
    {
        SerialPortStream portStream = null;
        foreach (SerialPortStream S in portStreams)
        {
            if (S.PortName == port)
            {
                portStream = S;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (portStream != null)
        {
            if (Send(portStream))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here's the exception :

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: Serial Port already opened
> at RJCP.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream.Open(Boolean setCommState)
> at RJCP.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream.Open()
> at Program.Send(SerialPortStream portStream) in 
> Program.cs:line 1973')
> ```

Comment: Note that ["attribute"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) has a specific meaning in .NET, and this most certainly not it. Perhaps you mean ["property"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) or ["field"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)?

Comment: You don't need such code in the first place. Your code should only open a new stream instance when it's needed, not have some global instance that has to be checked. There are no attributes at all in the question or any code that shows how this snippet is called. It's quite likely that multiple threads are trying to access the same port.

Comment: What is the type you use for portStream?

Comment: Are you sure the error is occurring in the above code?  Try stepping through the code to verify.

Comment: You can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jcurl/SerialPortStream/blob/v2.x/code/SerialPortStream.cs) and see that the exception you mention can only be thrown by the `portStream.Open()` call. Your assumption that it is caused by `IsOpen` is not correct.

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: @KlausGütter The exception error mention the line 3 of the first block of code.. I use Debian 8.7

Comment: Thanks for the answers i edit my post for reply

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I posted the code where i call this snippet. And it is possible that the async thread calls in a short time the function with the same port. Because to call the function who return error, I check the name of port in a list of portStreams instance and send the instance to port writer function.

Answer (score 0):

Look for conditions other than IsOpen .. it may be having a condition (status such as CDholding ) that prevent you Writing/Reading  although the Port is open.

Comment: But the error is not occured when i write or read on serial port but only when i check if it's opened or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that you are not calling the `SerialPortStream.Open()` or `Close()` on different threads. In general, the class is not threadsafe and could lead to the behaviour you observe.

Calling `portStream.Open();` will guarantee(*) that `portStream.IsOpen` returns `true`, else an exception should be raised.

The call `portStream.IsOpen` can not lead to the exception you describe, but `portStream.Open();` can. The `IsOpen` property only checks internal fields and has no exception raising in its path.

I checked the current code on the `v2.x` branch, and it blocks on `Open()` until it thinks it is really opened.

The exception you get is from here:

```cs
private void Open(bool setCommState) {
  ...
  if (m_NativeSerial.IsOpen) throw new InvalidOperationException("Serial Port already opened");
```

That gets it from here (`WinNativeSerial.cs`), which makes it pretty clear it was already opened (it's a native handle from Windows itself).

```
public bool IsOpen {
  get {
    if (m_IsDisposed) return false;
    SafeFileHandle handle = m_ComPortHandle;
    return handle != null && !handle.IsClosed && !handle.IsInvalid;
  }
}
```

So the code should be checked to make sure you're not trying to open and close on two different threads, which can lead it an invalid state.

(*) The guarantee assumes that there is not a driver problem and accessing the device doesn't cause problems immediately after the OS successfully opens the device.

Answer (score -1):

Modify your code to :

```
  try
        {
            if (!portStream.IsOpen)
            {
                portStream.Open();
            }
            //if (portStream.IsOpen) // line 1973 returned error already 
                                   //opened
           else
            {
                //build message and write on portstream
                try
                {
                    portStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            

        }
```

Comment: But in this case if portstream is not open, data/message will not be sent which is critical for me.

Comment: You are opening the portStream if it is not open:   if (!portStream.IsOpen)
            {
                portStream.Open();
            }

Comment: But with my code i open it if is not open and after if it's open i send message so in every case port is open. With your code you write message only if port is open

Comment: Try what is suggested, Will answer you if it does not work

Comment: This code is wrong.  If closed you will never write message.  Original code was much better.

Comment: Yes true like i said nothing writed on serial port.